# ViewState not persisting custom additions over postback

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a question, and it may be because I'm not understanding the way viewstate works.  I have some code that sets a viewstate variable in the setter for a property in a custom control I have made.

```
 public bool EditMode
    {
        get { return (bool)(ViewState["editMode" + this.ID] ?? false); }
        set {ViewState["editMode" + this.ID] = value;} 
    }
```

The editmode is being set during a button click event.

```
 public void shippingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (((Button)sender).CommandName== "Edit")
        {
            ctrlShippingAddress.EditMode = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Page.Validate();
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                ctrlShippingAddress.SaveAddress();
                ctrlShippingAddress.EditMode = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried manually setting it on page load in case I wasn't adding this to the viewstate at the correct point in the page cycle, but as I understand it events occur before render.  I have also tried adding ViewStateMode="Enabled" to the control, then to the page using it, then to the master page with no luck.

If I debug at the point of the get/set I see that viewstate is an empty collection (which doesn't make sense because it's also saving form data that is persisting as it should).

I appreciate any help.

Comment: After reviewing with a co-worker I discovered that the issue was in the pages node of the web config 

    <pages enableViewState="false">

needed to be set to true (clearly)

Comment: you should repost this comment as an answer and then accept it so if anyone finds this question in the future, they will also find a clearly marked answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing with a co-worker I discovered that the issue was in the pages node of the web.config

```
<pages enableViewState="false">
```

needed to be set to true

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to append the control ID to the ViewState key. I assume you're doing that for uniqueness, but it's not necessary.

The above may fix your problem, but if not try something like this instead:

```
public bool EditMode 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        bool editMode = false;
        if (ViewState["editMode"] != null)
            editMode = (bool)ViewState["editMode"];
        return editMode;
    } 
    set 
    {
        ViewState["editMode"] = value;
    }  
}
```